# how to change favicon odoo

Tags: website, favicon, odoo

I tried to change Favicon, but after different attempts, I didn't succeed, so here's what I did.

My version of odoo is 12.0.

- i went in : addons/web/static/src/img . i have deleted the favicon.ico, then I went to my odoo page but there was still the original favicon.

  - i went on my odoo page, I have activated the developer mode (with assets), then I went to configuration then general parameters, website, and there I was asked to change the favorite icon, which I did (respecting the dimensions). it didn't work.
  - I installed the Custom shortcut icon module, after installing it nothing has changed, I don't know where to go to use this module.

How to solve the problem, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution, the problem was that I had changed the extension of the favicon to **favicon.icon.old** to see if it had an impact on my odoo page.

It didn't have any because the system always took into account favicon.icon.old file

so what I did was I replaced the favicon with my favicon and it's worked